# Javascript - how to initialize super class if super class constructor takes arguments

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

Consider the following Javascript snippet,

```
var SuperClass = function(x){
    this.x = x;
    this.a = 5;
};

var SubClass = function(x){
}

function IntermediateClass(){};
IntermediateClass.prototype = SuperClass.prototype;
SubClass.prototype = new IntermediateClass;
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;
```

Now If i create an instance of SubClass, the object will not initialize the property "a" and "x".

```
var object = new SubClass;
//object.a == undefined
//object.x == undefined
```

While I understand why this happens, what is the cleanest way for the subclass to perform the initialization done by the super class constructor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a constructor function to inherit from a constructor function in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263353/how-to-get-a-constructor-function-to-inherit-from-a-constructor-function-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, there's a bunch of errors in that code.

This will make IntermediateClass a *sister* of SuperClass.

```
IntermediateClass.prototype = SuperClass.prototype;
```

You never need to do this, `constructor` is handled for you.

```
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;
```

That said, JavaScript *doesn't have classes*. Inheritance is object-based. You can't do what you're trying to do.

Instead, I would extract the initialisation in a separate function, then call it from the "subclass".

A better question is what you're trying to accomplish. You're trying to write JavaScript as if it was Java. It's not.

Comment: This post http://www.3site.eu/doc/#intermediate explains the reasons for using IntermediateClass.