# How to inherit correctly in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

My understanding is that "hasOwnProperty" returns true if the object has a given member without check the prototype chain. But when I inherit fro other object, I see all members in the last object itself.

Consider the following example:

```
var Object1 = function (param) {
    this.prop1 = "p1 " + param;
    this.prop2 = "p2 " + param;
};

var Object2 = function (param) {
    Object1.apply(this, arguments);
    this.prop3 = 'p3' + param;
};

Object2.prototype = new Object1();

var b = new Object2('this is Object 2');

for (var v in b)
    print(v + ": " + b[v] + (b.hasOwnProperty(v)?' (own)':' (inherited)'));
```

This code prints:

```
--prop1: p1 this is Object 2 (own)
--prop2: p2 this is Object 2 (own)
--prop3: p3this is Object 2 (own)
```

If I take a look on the debugger I see:

```
b
  Object2
    prop1: "p1 this is Object 2"
    prop2: "p2 this is Object 2"
    prop3: "p3this is Object 2"
    __proto__: Object1
```

But, id I remove the `apply` line, all makes more sense, but base object it is not initialized:

```
--prop3: p3this is Object 2 (own)
--prop1: p1 undefined (inherited)
--prop2: p2 undefined (inherited)
```

Now I see in the debugger:

```
b
  Object2
    prop3: "p3this is Object 2"
    __proto__: Object1
      prop1: "p1 undefined"
      prop2: "p2 undefined"
      __proto__: Object
```

As far as I know, `apply` it's like ... execute the super class constructor, so super members are initialized correctly, but apparently that changes the shape of the child object.

Why is this happening? What is the correct way -or at least the less messy- to inherit in JS?

I am taking a look to some information about it, and apparently each developer has different feelings about how to do it.

Regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performing Inheritance in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586915/performing-inheritance-in-javascript)

Comment: @John Hartsock actually not, this "issue" also happens on the examples of that thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) is not at all like executing the super class constructor.  As a construct, it executes *any* function **in the scope of the first provided argument**.  When you pass `this` to your `Object1` function (which you execute as a function, not as a constructor), you are passing through the scope in which your second function (`Object2`) is being executed.

To see what's happening, try executing `Object1("param")` **without** `new`:

```
Object1("test");
```

When we execute `new Object1("test")` we get back an object that looks like this:

```
Object { prop1="p1 test", prop2="p2 test"}
```

But when we execute `Object1("test")` we get back `undefined` ... and on the object equal to `this` (most likely `window` in the case of browser JavaScript) we find two new variables ... `prop1` and `prop2`.

## What happened?

The key here is that:

```
Object1("param") !== new Object1("param");
```

The first version (`Object1("param")`) executes a function (`Object1`) in some *already existing* scope (in browser JavaScript the most common scope is the top-level scope where `this === window`.)  This is the way you are invoking `Object1` when you call `Object1.apply(this)`.

The second version (`new Object1("param")`) executes a function **as a constructor** - that is, it creates a **new** object and sets `this` to be that new object.  If we were to use the same `apply` function to demonstrate this we would write `Object1.apply({})`;

For one of the most definitive answers I have ever seen on the subject of how to do OOP-like programming *right* in a JavaScript environment, see [Bobince's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript/1598077#1598077).

Comment: Thanks a million for the explanation.