# How to eliminate code repetition between different View Model modules?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

My JS is organized into viewmodels and services.  The services are mostly concerned with AJAX calls, whereas my viewModels describe the view that they're used in.

I have two view models now - StoreViewModel, and MyStoreViewModel.  In each of these, I have the following:

```
function MyStoreVm(model) {
    var self = this;

    self.doThis = function(){
        // do stuff 
        self.doThat();
    };
}
```

Then:

```
function StoreVm(model) {
    var self = this;

    self.doThis = function(){
        // do stuff 
        self.doThat();
    };
}
```

I come from a C# background - normally I would just use inheritance in this kind of situation.  How can I eliminate this code repetition between two distinct modules / viewmodels, by having them inherit from a third, shared module?

More details: These are being used in an MVC view where I have knockout bindings depending on whether or not the store is MyStore:

```
@if (!Model.IsMyStore) {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(ko.applyBindings(new StoreVm(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() })))));
    </script>
} else if (Model.IsMyStore) {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(ko.applyBindings(new MyStoreVm(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() }).Sanitize()))));
    </script>
}
```

**UPDATE**

I looked into some of the suggestions below, but none seemed clean and simple enough for my novice skills.  I tried the following which seems to work:

```
function BaseStore(model){
    self.doThis = function(){
        // do stuff 
        self.doThat();
    };
    // and a whole lot of other shared code
}

function StoreVm(model) {
    var storeVm = new BaseStoreVm(model)
    var self = storeVm;
    self.isolatedFunctionForGenericStores = function(){stuff}
    // other stuff for only this type
    return storeVm;
}

function MyStoreVm(model) {
    var myStoreVm = new BaseStoreVm(model)
    var self = myStoreVm;
    self.isolatedFunctionForMyStore = function(){stuff}
    // other stuff for only this type
    return myStoreVm;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two child types that need to inherit from the same parent, you can do:

```
function Parent( foo ) {
  this.foo = foo;
}
Parent.prototype.method = function() {
  console.log( this.foo );
};

function Child1() {
  Parent.call( this, "bar" );
}
Child1.prototype = Object.create( Parent.prototype );
Child1.prototype.constructor = Child1;

function Child2() {
  Parent.call( this, "qux" );
}
Child2.prototype = Object.create( Parent.prototype );
Child2.prototype.constructor = Child2;

var parent = new Parent("blah");
var child1 = new Child1();
var child2 = new Child2();

parent.method();  // => "blah"
child1.method();  // => "bar"
child2.method();  // => "qux"
```

Comment: Sorry - they should both inherit from a single other function.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I tried your suggestion but got myself confused while putting everything together.  I was able to get it working via the code in my update - what are your thoughts on this approach?

Answer (score 0):

First you should understand how `JavaScript` implement inheritance. `JavaScript` is a prototype-based language which contains no class statement, such as is found in `C#`. Instead, it uses functions as classes(no classes, just objects).
So what we have here is ***objects*** inherit from other ***objects*** (*now you might need to get some coffee*).

So then `JavaScript` does not give you the full power of inheritance and polymorphism you get in `C#`.
If you want to know ways to implement inheritance in JS:

1. [SO: Performing inheritance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586915/performing-inheritance-in-javascript)
2. [My Blog: Javascript Inheritance techniques](http://ebramtharwat.tk/2013/11/23/javascript-inheritance-techniques/)

Back to your question, i think you may need to implement ***[The Factory Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#factorypatternjavascript)***. So your js code could be like that:

```
function MyStoreVm(model) {
    var self = this;
    self.doThis = function() {
        // do stuff 
        self.doThat();
    };
}

function StoreVm(model) {
    var self = this;
    self.doThis = function() {
        // do stuff 
        self.doThat();
    };
}
// Define factory object that create your proper store object
// StoreFactory takes the model as input.
// You can change it to accept seconf parameter that define class type
function StoreFactory() {
    this.classType == "MyStoreVm"; // default value
    this.createStore = function(model) {
        if (model.IsMyStore === true)
            this.classType = MyStoreVm;
        else
            this.classType = StoreVm;
        return new this.classType(model);
    }
}
```

Then in your MVC view:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mystoreFactory = new StoreFactory();
    ko.applyBindings(mystoreFactory.createStore((@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, new JsonSerializerSettings() {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    })))));
});
```

Comment: Kind of funny how you mention JavaScript being a prototype based language and then produce sample code that makes no use of it at all.

Comment: @HMR you right.. i just tried to figure how to solve the problem, not to explain inheritance in details

Comment: Thanks ebram.  Though I'm confused - how does this eliminate the code duplication?  I'm trying to get simpler and DRYer by pushing the shared code out of both modules and into one, shared module.

Comment: i think JS do not provide that flexability you want. At the end you must state which sub-class type you want your object to be **not** the the base-class(no polymorphism here in JS)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Klass.js](http://dustindiaz.com/klass). While this is basically the same as creating your own prototypes and inheritance methods, it's nice to use. It's also AMD aware.

```
// base class
var Store = klass(function() {
    var self = this;
    // add properties here
}).methods({
    doThis: function () {
        // do this
    },
    doThat: function () {
        // do that
    }
});
return Store;

// create the first constructor
var myStoreVm = Store.extend(function () {
    // super class is called
}).methods({
    doThis: function(){
        this.supr(); // call Store.doThis
        // some other code
    }
});
return myStoreVm;

// create the second constructor
var storeVm = Store.extend(function () {
    // super class is called
}).methods({
    doThis: function(){
        // override Store.doThis with my own code
    }
});
return storeVm;
```