# How to inherit from vscode.TreeDataProvider<Dependency> in js?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want create Visual Studio Code extension in JS (I don't want use TS), I encountered problem with inheritance. I need inherit from TreeDataProvider, how to do it in JS?

```
// Fragment of code where I need this:
let MyCustomTreeDataProvider = ???

vscode.window.registerTreeDataProvider('custom-list', MyCustomTreeDataProvider);
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the tree view extension sample? https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/tree-view-sample

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performing inheritance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586915/performing-inheritance-in-javascript)